# Using Actix from a Tokio App: mixing actix_web::main and tokio::main?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio, actix-web

Currently I have a main written like the [async example for the `Reqwest` library](https://crates.io/crates/reqwest).

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
```

We can use the exact example there for this. Now I want to basically add a `-l <port>` flag to alter the behavior of my application and when triggered in such a fashion, I want it to listen on the port and run a web server. I'm wanting to use [Actix Web](https://actix.rs/) which is documented like this,

```
#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
```

How can I synthesize two `fn main`: one decorated with `#[actix_web::main]` and one decorated with `#[tokio::main]` to use Actix Web from within an application that already uses Tokio? I can't find any documentation on
this? How do we go about using Tokio stuff from an Actix Web server, and how do we port a Tokio application to an Actix Web application?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/actix/examples/blob/master/basics/run-in-thread/src/main.rs

Comment: I doubt you can have multiple main since you can only have one main entry

Comment: You can't have multiple `main` functions, but since Actix runs on Tokio anyway there might be a way to tell Actix to use an existing Tokio runtime instead of starting its own.

Comment: @NjugunaMureithi here is an updated link https://github.com/actix/examples/blob/master/run-in-thread/src/main.rs

Answer (score 17):

Since Actix-web internally uses Tokio, when you use `#[actix_web::main]`, you will be able to use all the usual Tokio utilities just as if you had used `#[tokio::main]`.

However be aware that you need to match up the versions of Tokio correctly. Actix-web version `3.x.y` uses Tokio `0.2.x`, so when using that version of Actix, you need to use utilities that work with that version of Tokio. To use the latest version of Tokio, you need to use the `4.0.0-beta.x` versions of Actix-web instead.

Feel free to edit this answer once Actix-web 4 is out of beta.

Comment: Thank you! Just leaving some breadcrumbs here... I was using Actix-Web `3` with reqwest `0.11` and was getting the error `thread 'actix-rt:worker:2' panicked at 'there is no reactor running, must be called from the context of a Tokio 1.x runtime'`

Comment: Actix-web is now out of beta. Here are some usefull links: [issue tracking this on Github](https://github.com/actix/actix-web/issues/1283) ; [migration guide](https://github.com/actix/actix-web/blob/master/actix-web/MIGRATION-4.0.md)